# QLineEdit::text is incomplete with Android virtual keyboard

Tags: android, qt, virtual-keyboard

If I use Android native virtual keyboard, `QLineEdit` can not get all inputed words. (Qt 5.7,  Android 6)

If I input "Force input" (like on the picture) and call

```
QLineEdit::text()
```

I get only "Force ".

How do I get the whole text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "input" is still being typed/inputted (notice the underline) and is not yet committed to the application. You can force to commit everything now using [`QInputMethod::commit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#commit):

> Commits the word user is currently composing to the editor. The
>   function is mostly needed by the input methods with text prediction
>   features and by the methods where the script used for typing
>   characters is different from the script that actually gets appended to
>   the editor. Any kind of action that interrupts the text composing
>   needs to flush the composing state by calling the commit() function,
>   for example when the cursor is moved elsewhere.

Afterwards, you should be able to retrieve all the text using `QLineEdit::text`.

**Alternative**: `QLineEdit::displayText`

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100195/7621674), it may be possible to use [`QLineEdit::displayText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#displayText-prop) without calling `QInputMethod::commit` first.

Comment: `QLineEdit::displayText` did not help, but this decision helped me
`QInputMethod *input = QApplication::inputMethod();`
`input->commit();`
Thanks!