# TextField text field doesn't return value on QML | QT 5.12

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qml, textfield

i need an help.
So this is my code:

```
TextField {
    id: passwordIDText
    placeholderText: "Insert text..."
    color: "Black"
    font.bold: true
    font.pixelSize: 21
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: parent.height / 10
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    text: "aaa"
}
```

I use Android 8 (P20), QT 12.4, Android NDK 20 and Android SDK 28.
So when i click the button on the android screen (i'm using 20 to testing), in debug, for get the passwordIDText.text, the field is empty, why ?? But if i set text: "aaa" hard coded, i get passwordIDText.text = "aaa".

The problem look TextField don't get the value inserted by the user. I've inserted 123456 on TextField on screen and click on Button:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        var test = passwordIDText.text;
        //passwordIDText.text is empty wtf !??

    }
}
```

So someone have the same problem ? On the older Android version TextField works correctly.

My configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it might be an issue similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088182/how-to-make-qml-textfield-binding-work-under-android), related to predictive text not being committed at the time you need to access it.

Try using `passwordIDText.displayText` instead of `passwordIDText.text`.

Alternatively you can turn down predictive text input:

`inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText`

Answer (score 1):

'ImhNoPredictiveText' didn't solve my problem in Qt 5.14. so i used

```
inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhSensitiveData
```

and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you don't want to disable user dictionary or word prediction you should use [deselect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#deselect-method) every time before getting text.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
Button{
...
   onClicked:{
       focus = true
       console.log(textarea.text)
   }
...

}

TextArea{
    id: textarea
}
```

Then the Text is really reachable under textarea.text

hope it helps!