# TextArea does not receive text until you enter a space

Tags: android, qt, qml

Qt 5.12.3 / QtQuick 2.12 / QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Qml component TextArea behavior on Android (Android 8 with MIUI).
When I type text into TextArea, TextArea qml does not receive an onTextChanged event with the text entered until a space is entered. Is it possible to fix or  workaround?

```
TextArea {
    onTextChanged: console.log("onTextChanged:", text)
}
```

console has these messages:

```
W MyApp: {default} [W] [28.08.19 17:38:54.738] Input method out of sync "" 12
```

With Qt 5.13.0 / QtQuick 2.13 / QtQuick.Controls 2.13
the behavior is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextField text field doesn't return value on QML | QT 5.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649760/textfield-text-field-doesnt-return-value-on-qml-qt-5-12). Try with `onDisplayTextChanged: console.log("onTextChanged:", displayText)`

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
TextArea {
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhSensitiveData
    onTextChanged: {
        console.log("onTextChanged:", text)
    }
}

// with preText in keyboard

TextArea {
    onTextChanged: {
        deselect()
        console.log("onTextChanged:", text)
    }
}
```

use clear() to remove text in display.